# How to change secondary font used by gnome terminal?

Tags: terminal, fonts, gnome-terminal, i18n

Some environment infos:

- Arch Linux
- KDE Plasma 5.10.4
- GNOME Terminal 3.24.2 Using VTE version 0.48.3 +GNUTLS

I set to use Ubuntu Mono Regular font in gnome terminal profile.
And Latin characters do render nicely. The problem is I don't
like the default CJK font chosen somehow automatically by it to
render Chinese characters.

I have installed desired CJK fonts such as
Noto fonts, WenQuanYi fonts, and configured to use them in fontconfig. By such,
CJK characters render by desired font in Chrome.
As far as I can tell, the incorrect font is used solely by
gnome terminal. (Maybe that's because it use different
mechanism for choosing font to use? Pango/Xft I guess?)

I would like to know *how* the CJK font is chosen (as it is not
settable in gnome terminal profile) and how can I customize it?